SCSI cable doesn't fit my computer, need adapter
I have some old Jaz disks that I would like to access, but the computer that I have with a built in Jaz drive, an old Compaq Pressario, does not function and cannot be repaired. I purchased an external Jaz drive on eBay, hoping to be able to use it to access the old disks, but the cable does not fit my computer.


They appear to be the same size, but the cable has more pins than there are holes in the SCSI port, and the band around the pins is too small to fit over the port. The SCSI port has 25 holes. The SCSI cable has about twice that many pins, but I was unable to count them. The SCSI cable uses a clamp connection, while the SCSI port expects two screws to hold the cable in place.
Is there an adapter that I can use to fit the SCSI cable onto the SCSI port? If so, what is the part number or designation for it? I see a lot of SCSI adapters online, but I don't know which one to order. Alternately, is there an adapter that would let me use the SCSI cable with a USB port? If so, what is the part number or designation? Thank you.

One thing you should be aware of is that there are MANY variations of SCSI.  Do NOT expect them to be compatible.  I believe there are at least 4 versions (and that is old information), variations like "LV" (low voltage) and "D" (differential), as well as many different connector types.  Find out exactly what you need and buy accordingly.  Also, there were indeed DB connectors with more than 25 pins for SCSI (and those pins are fragile!).

What your image appears to show is that the computer has a parallel port, used in legacy machines for connecting to printers (primarily). "Back in the day," one could purchase an external removable diskette drive that connected to the parallel port.
If you have determined that you have a SCSI drive (image is fuzzy), the two are not compatible.
You may be able to find an add-in card that converts your internal bus to SCSI, perhaps via eBay or other marketplace for obsolete devices, to make the connection you desire.
This could also result in another challenge to find appropriate drivers for your operating system to recognize the new device and/or interface card.

I apologize for the fuzzy image; I was unable to get it any sharper. It is definitely a SCSI port and not a parallel port, as it has the SCSI symbol underneath it. You can see that on the top image.
https://th.bing.com/th?id=ODL.269dd0133ca24949e0235ff0ca581599&w=169&h=177&c=10&rs=1&qlt=99&o=6&dpr=1.3&pid=13.1

It is still a parallel port connector that has been used for SCSI.

A SCSI port is a type of parallel port, and a printer port has 25 holes, so yes. Do you know of an adapter that I can use to connect the cable to the port?

One can create almost any kind of cable, but the interface protocol is a critical aspect. Parallel printers use one protocol, SCSI devices use another. If you have a SCSI device, the cable creation isn't going to be insurmountable, but you still have to get the two devices to communicate (drivers, etc.)

I contacted my local computer repair shop for assistance, asking them whether they could modify the computer to work with the SCSI cable. This was their response:
"It appears that it is a parallel printer port on the computer. Scsi adapters have to be installed and aren’t typically part of a stock computer. I apologize, we won’t be able to help you with this because of the age of the computer, and adapter you would need."
I then contacted the seller of the Jaz drive asking him if he still had the computer that it worked with and whether he could sell it to me, but he told me he no longer had it, so I returned the Jaz drive for a refund. I then sent the Jaz disks to a data transfer service to have them copied to a flash drive.
